# Partial mocking a non static method does not call a private static method inside it

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I am using Powermock to write test case for one of my methods which is something like this :

```
class A{
  static String hello = "hello";
  private void static init(String s){
      hello = hello+" "+s;
  }
  public String getString(String s){
      init(s);
      return hello;
 }
}

class B{
    A a = new A();
    public String printHelloWorld(){            
        return a.getString("World")+" from Hawaii";     
    }
}
```

I am trying to test getStringFromA method of class B by mocking the method getString of class A using PowerMock like this :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
class TestClass{
  @Test
  public void testMethod(){

      //Mock Creation
      A dummy = createPartialMock(A.class,"getString",String.class);

     //Expect
     expectNew(A.class).andReturn(dummy);
     expect(dummy.getString("World")).andReturn("Hello World");

     //Replay
     replayAll();

     //Execute
     B b = new B();
     b.printHelloWorld();
  }
}
```

The problem is that this does not seem to work. getString() method of class A does not execute the private static method init(). I thought that this is because we are mocking the method getString(). However if the method getString() is also made static execution goes to init method.
What could be the reason of this anomaly.

Thanks,
Manas

Comment: `init()` is a static method and it tries to change `hello` which is a class member. You cannot have inside a static method a reference to a class member! This code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @SHG: Thanks for pointing it out. corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Works exactly as expected. From the [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockpartial):

> PowerMock.createPartialMock(ClassToPartiallyMock.class, "nameOfTheFirstMethodToMock", "nameOfTheSecondMethodToMock") to create a mock object that only mocks the methods with name nameOfTheFirstMethodToMock ...

You are *instructing* PowerMock to **mock** `getString()`. Mocking means: it is a dummy, not doing **anything**.

In that sense: you should step back and read *how* to use mocking to do proper unit testing. You are not even clear on whether you want to test class A or B.

You see, to test class B, you do not need PowerMock or partial mocking. You simply do something like this:

```
A mockedA = mock(A.class);
when(mockedA.getString("foo")).thenReturn("bar");

B underTest = new B(mockedA);
assertThat(b.printHelloWorld(), is("bar from hawaii"));
```

or something alike. The above is using Mockito calls, but EasyMock isn't much different.

The point is: simply *provide* an instance of class A to B instead of doing `new` within the B class, and all your need for enhanced mocking features completely vanishes.

In other words: no partial mocking required here. And even if you would want to go for partial mocking - read the documentation carefully. All of these things are **fully** documented.